# Python Utility To Compare Data Between Sql Server Tables and Similar Snowflake Tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm a newbie to python and would require your help in building this utility.

**Use case**: I need to build a python utility which compares and does basic data validation like row count, count of columns on those tables between sql server and snowflake tables. The list of the tables needs to be extracted by reading and looping an excel file (list of sql server tables v/s snowflake tables listed there.). The difference is to be written in a separate file.

Code :

```
# -------------- Import packages needed ----------------------------
import sys, os, pyodbc, datetime, collections
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector as sf
import sqlalchemy as sa
#import SNCC_Conn as sfconn

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 999)


# set params for Snowflake Connection
sncc_auth = 'externalbrowser'
sncc_user = 'xxx'
sncc_warehouse = 'xxx'
sncc_db = 'xxx'
sncc_sch = 'SFSCHEMA'
sncc_tbl = 'TABLE_1'

sncc_qry = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+sncc_sch+'.'+sncc_tbl+''
#sncc_qry1 = 'SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME ='+sncc_tbl''

sf_qry = r'' + sncc_qry

# set params for SQL Connection TST . 

sql_srvr = 'xxxx'
sql_db = 'xxx'
sql_user = 'xxx'
sql_pwd = 'xxx'
sql_driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
sql_sch = 'SQLSCHEMA'
sql_tbl = 'TABLE_1'

ms_sql_qry = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+sql_sch+'.' +sql_tbl+''
#ms_sql_qry1 = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'allegro' and TABLE_NAME = 'trade''

fileName = 'SQL_SF_Comparison'


# --------------------------- Snowflake Connection ---------------------------


try:
    sf_conn = sf.connect(authenticator='externalbrowser',
                         user='xxxx',
                         account='xxx', 
                         warehouse='xxx', 
                         database='xxx',       
                         schema ='',
                         role=''  
                         )
except Exception as e:
    print('Connection Failed. Please try again.')
    print('Error: ' + str(e) )
    quit()

print('Snowflake Connection established!')

print(sf_qry)

try:

    # excute the query
    sf_conn.execute(sf_qry)
    
    # Fetch all snowflake results into a Pandas Dataframe
    sf_df = sf_conn.fetch_pandas_all()

    # Make all Dataframe Columns Uppercase
    sf_df.columns = map(str.upper, sf_df.columns)

    # Print out results on screen during development phase.
    print(sf_df)
    print(sf_df.columns)
    

    print('Snowflake Dataframe Load Successful.')
    
    
except Exception as e:
    print('Snowflake Dataframe load Unsuccessful. Please try again.')
    print('Error: ' + str(e) )



# # ---------------------------  SQL Server Connection  ---------------------------
try:
    # single '\' provides a concat to the DRIVE, SERVER, DATABASE, trusted connection lines, as if a single line of code.
    sql_conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+sql_driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+sql_srvr+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+sql_db+';UID='+sql_user+';PWD='+ sql_pwd+'') # Using Windows User Account for authentication.
    cursor = sql_conn.cursor()

    print('SQL Server Connection established!')
    
    print(ms_sql_qry)

except Exception as e:
    print('Connection Failed. Please try again.')
    print('Error: ' + str(e) )


try: 
    # Query results and place them in variable
    # cursor.execute(sql_qry)
    sql_qry = pd.read_sql_query(ms_sql_qry,sql_conn)
    
    # Put results into a Data Frame from Pandas
    sql_df = pd.DataFrame(sql_qry)

    # Make all Dataframe Columns Uppercase
    sql_df.columns = map(str.upper, sql_df.columns)
    
 
    # Print out results during development phase.
    print(sql_df)
    print(sql_df.columns)
    
    print('SQL Server Dataframe Load Successful')
    print('Comparing SQL to SNCC Dataframes')


    #/********************* COMPARISON SCRIPT **************/
    
    #sql_df.compare(sncc_df)
    
    # Compare the two DataFrames and produce results from Source (sql_df) that do not match Target (sf_df).

    df_diff = sql_df[sf_df != sql_df]
    
    # print out results of differences during development phase.
    print(df_diff)
    
    
    # Export out to CSV using a variable for the name of the file, future state.
    df_diff.to_csv(r'D:\PythonResults\DataDiff_' + fileName + '.csv', index = False)
    
    print('Datafram output from comparison outputed to PythonResults folder in Documents as DataDiff_' + fileName + 'csv.')
    

except pyodbc.Error as e:
    # Message stating export unsuccessful.
    print("MSSQL Dataframe load unsuccessful.")


finally:
    
    sf_conn.close()
    print("Connection to Snowflake closed")

    sql_conn.commit()
    sql_conn.close()
    print("Connection to MSSQL Server closed")
```

File Data and file name :

[Tables.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZBlZ.png)

Help me in completing the code in extracting the list of tables from the excel file and loop the data and load them to datframes and compare them

Answer (score 0):

See [pyodbc Connecting to Microsoft Excel](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Microsoft-Excel) for details on reading from Excel.